# Adding to a Groovy list in a builder-esqe way

Tags: groovy

Here's the most groovy way I've seen so far:

```
threads = []
threads << makeAThread("1")
threads << makeAThread("2")
```

But I want to do:

```
threads = []
threads {
    << makeAThread("1")
    << makeAThread("2")
 }
```

Or if I have to:

```
threads = []
threads {
    add(makeAThread("1"))
    add(makeAThread("2"))
 }
```

Therefore I'm needing builder, DSL advice.

This is what I did (modifying the answer I accepted):

```
threads = []
threads.with {
    add makeAThread("1")
    add makeAThread("2")
}
```

Comment: `def threads = ['1', '2'].collect { makeAThread it }` though it is not builder-esqe way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish either of your examples using `with`.

```
threads = []
threads.with {
    it << makeAThread("1")
    it << makeAThread("2")
}
```

or

```
threads = []
threads.with {
    add(makeAThread("1"))
    add(makeAThread("2"))
}
```

`with` makes every call or property access apply to the given object, in this case `threads`. The `leftShift()` operator, `<<`, needs an explicit left hand side, in this case `it`.

Comment: All the answers are good (short elegant), but I like this one best as it fits my builder ideals. However I modified - see the last code block in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Why not: `def threads = [makeAThread("1"), makeAThread("2")]`?

Answer (score 1):

If @Opal's solution doesn't suit you, you can chain `<<` calls:

```
threads = [] << makeAThread("1") << makeAThread("2")
```